# Angular2: touchStart and touchEnd are not responding properly in mobile view

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular5, angular6

In css we have hover property, so to apply that hover in mobile view I am trying to apply touchstart and touchend events. But events are not responding properly.

Below are my both events

```
 @HostListener('touchstart', ['$event']) onTouchStart(event: Event): void {
    if (event) {
      event.preventDefault();
    }
    let part = this.el.nativeElement.querySelector('.icon-interface-question-mark');
    this.renderer.setElementStyle(part, 'color', 'green');
  }



  @HostListener('touchend', ['$event']) onTouchEnd(event: Event): void {
    if (event) {
      event.preventDefault();
    }
    let part = this.el.nativeElement.querySelector('.icon-interface-question-mark');
    this.renderer.setElementStyle(part, 'display', 'yellow');
  }
```

Below is my css

```
.account-outlook-wrapper {
  .icon-interface-question-mark {
    color: yellow;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;

    &:hover {
      color: green;
    }
  }
```

To check it, I changed the normal css to

```
.account-outlook-wrapper {
      .icon-interface-question-mark {
        color: orange;
        position: relative;
        cursor: pointer;

        &:hover {
          color: red;
        }
      }
```

But because of touchstart event, the color was green in window browser although it was supposed to work in mobile view only. Please let me know If I am not using both events properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

touch events works fine.

there is other problems (not CSS or events):

1. There is no `setElementStyle` method in Renderer2. use **setStyle**
2. You try to set `yellow` color as value of `display`. but `display` dont accept color

see this example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-s5wfhf

Comment: I was not able to see ontouchstart and ontouchend changes in ipad and ipad pro, its working fine in other mobile devices